# remove double quotes ("") from csv import to mysql Database in asp.net

Tags: c#, mysql, asp.net, csv

I am trying to import bulk data from my csv file. Data gets imported correctly but it adds under double quote (""). I don't want it to add it. Below is code I am using

```
protected void importSalesData()
{
    //Upload and save the file
    string csvPath = Server.MapPath("/csv/") + Path.GetFileName(file1.PostedFile.FileName);
    file1.SaveAs(csvPath);

    string strFile = file1.PostedFile.FileName;
    string connectMySQL = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("loyalty").ConnectionString;
    using (MySqlConnection cn1 = new MySqlConnection(connectMySQL)) {
        cn1.Open();
        MySqlBulkLoader bcp1 = new MySqlBulkLoader(cn1);
        bcp1.TableName = "salesData";
        //Create ProductOrder table into MYSQL database...
        bcp1.FieldTerminator = ",";

        bcp1.LineTerminator = Constants.vbCr + Constants.vbLf;
        bcp1.FileName = "F:/MY WEB/Foxbox Loyalty/Foxbox Loyalty/website/csv/" + strFile;
        bcp1.NumberOfLinesToSkip = 1;
        bcp1.Load();
    }
}
```

Comment: what about setting the FieldQuotationCharacter  and FieldQuotationOptional properties?

Comment: See https://dev.mysql.com/doc/dev/connector-net/6.10/html/P_MySql_Data_MySqlClient_MySqlBulkLoader_FieldQuotationCharacter.htm

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try setting the `MySqlBulkLoader.FieldQuotationCharacter` property to `"` (double quote) and `MySqlBulkLoader.FieldQuotationOptional` to `false`.

`MySqlBulkLoader` constructs a MySQL `LOAD DATA` command and then executes it. The documentation does not clearly describe what affect these properties has on loading the data, however, the [source code](https://github.com/mysql/mysql-connector-net/blob/fcb0843b4140e648195be7ff2ef0f20dda14e45b/Source/MySql.Data/BulkLoader.cs#L350) does.